# How to apply JQuery function to all elements except some elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am kind of stuck on this one. I have webapp where I use simple JQuery plugin:

```
$.extend($.fn.disableTextSelect = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        if($.browser.mozilla){//Firefox
            $(this).css('MozUserSelect','none');
        }else if($.browser.msie){//IE
            $(this).bind('selectstart',function(){return false;});
        }else if ($.browser.webkit) { // chrome, webkit
          $(this).css('webkitUserSelect','none');
          this.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
        }else{//Opera, etc.
            $(this).mousedown(function(){return false;});
        }
    });
});
```

This plugin generally disables mouse text selects on all the browsers. I call it on #desktop element, which is basically main wrapper:

```
$('#desktop').disableTextSelect();
```

I use this, because it disables mouse text selects on all the elements inside #desktop. However, there are some of elements in #desktop, which I want to have normal text select behaviour. Is there some easy way how to implement code, that would make exception to the global rule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be do do some filtering before you start your main logic.

```
$.extend($.fn.disableTextSelect = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        if ($(this).parents('#excludedItems').length) { //or any other logic here
            return true; //move to the next item
        }

        if($.browser.mozilla){//Firefox
            $(this).css('MozUserSelect','none');
        }else if($.browser.msie){//IE
            $(this).bind('selectstart',function(){return false;});
        }else if ($.browser.webkit) { // chrome, webkit
          $(this).css('webkitUserSelect','none');
          this.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
        }else{//Opera, etc.
            $(this).mousedown(function(){return false;});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

JQuery supports the `not()` selector ([here](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)).  You could use the distinguishing feature of those elements you wish to have normal behaviour, as the argument to the `not()` selector

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work for child elements. Or am I doing something wrong ?
    $('#desktop').not('table,thead,th,tr,td').disableTextSelect();

Comment: The problem is that the children of `desktop` inherit the CSS properties. Try to set the CSS values again, using `$('table').css('webkitUserSelect', 'text')` et cetera

Comment: ok, so basically i would use solution as lonesomeday suggested bellow and implement it as a feature of the plugin to set specific elements with .css() as you said.